# Which polynomials are resultants?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $f(x,y),g(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ with degrees $\deg(f)=m,\deg(g)=n$.  Considering these polynomials as univariate polynomials in $y$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the resultant $\text{res}(f,g)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is of degree $\leq mn$ (AFAIK this is the crux of Bezout's theorem).

Does the converse hold?  That is, is it the case that for every $h(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\deg(h)=mn$, there exist $f(x,y),g(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ such that $\deg(f)=m,\deg(g)=n$ and $h=\text{res}(f,g)$?

Possibly equivalent question: Is it the case that for every element $\alpha$ of a field extension $E/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $mn$, there exist polynomials $f(x,y),g(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ with $\deg(f)=m,\deg(g)=n$ such that $\alpha$ is a root of $\text{res}(f.g)$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If $f=xy+1, g=y+1$, then $m=2, n=1$. But the resultant is $x-1$, which has degree one and not 2=mn$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I mean to say that the degree of the resultant is $\leq mn$. I will correct my question shortly.

Comment: For $m=n>2$, I bet this fails.  For $E/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n^2$, for $\alpha\in E$, and for varying $\beta\in E$, you ask whether the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear evaluation map, $e_{\alpha,\beta}: \mathbb{Q}[x,y]_n \to E$, $f(x,y) \mapsto f(\alpha,\beta)$, has kernel of dimension $2$.  The domain has dimension $(n+1)(n+2)/2$.  The target has dimension $n^2$.  Thinking of $E$ as an affine $n^2$-space over $\mathbb{Q}$, those $\beta$ where this matrix of degree $n$ polynomials has nullity $2$ is a closed subscheme of codimension $\leq (n-1)(n-2)$.  So likely there are no rational solutions for $n>2$.